# Change in random state value changes the model accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

While testing my linear regression model, I find that changing the `random_state` parameter in `train_test_split` changes the model accuracy.

To elaborate, my train test split is as follows:

```
boston_data = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston_data.data, columns=boston_data.feature_names)
y = pd.DataFrame(boston_data.target, columns=['MEDV'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

And my model is as follows:

```
steps = [
    ('regr', Lasso())
]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

parameters = {
    'regr__alpha': np.logspace(-4, -0.5, 40)
}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Now, for example, for the current scenario (where `random_state` = 42) the test score is 0.725. However, if I change it to 43, the test score comes down to 0.7.

I understand that `random_state` signifies what set of data will be in test and training set. Having said that, I want to know, if there's way to get a stable result?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand - if you won't change `random_state` - it'll give you stable result isn't it?

Comment: Hi @MaxU , thanks again for your answer! :) But, the reason, why I asked the question: which random state to stick to? And how to be sure that what is my actual model accuracy, when it keeps on changing just by changing the test set?

Comment: I think it's normal that it's changing for changed test set... unless you have accuracy `1.0`, which is happening because of `data leakage` - you definitely don't want this situation...

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I will provide an answer since there currently isn't one and random state confused me a little at first.

When you split you data into training and testing for machine learning models, this is done randomly to avoid potential selection biases arising. Whilst this is beneficial for obtaining non-biased resuts, it also means that results can differ from run to run.

To avoid this, random state can be used to ensure that results with the same data are fixed between runs. This is helpful when you are changing variables or parameters further up in your model because if you keep the random state as a fixed number then you know any changes in model accuaracy are due to the changes you have made, and not because of a different split in the data. Once the model is trained, random state could be removed and the model could be run multiple times with an average of all the results taken to provide a true reflection of the quality of the model.

Hence, when training machine learning models it is a good idea to keep random states as a fixed numbers at any point in the machine learning process until properly trained. So, in answer to the question, there is no random state number that should be chosen , but choosing any random state at all points in the your machine learning process where random state is available will ensure stable results throughout.